# PHP replaced a tag with custom texts not working

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm working on a PHP preg_replace script to replace a tag with some new texs

ex-  I want to replace texts inside

My Code is here

```
$string= '<p style="margin: 0 0 16px;">Your order is shipped and 
    it’s on the way to your address, It will receive to you within 
   <tag>current_date format=”jS F Y” oddt=”” shipdays=”16″</tag></p>';

    $search = "/[^<tag>](.*)[^<\/tag>]/";

    $replace = "22nd January 2019 and 27th January";


    echo $sv= preg_replace($search,$replace,$string);
```

But the output shows like this

```
22nd January 2019 and 27th January 201922nd January 2019 and 27th January 201922nd January 2019 and 27th January 201922nd January 2019 and 27th January 201922nd January 2019 and 27th January 201922nd January 2019 and 27th January 201922nd January 2019 and 27th January 201922nd January 2019 and 27th January 201922nd January 2019 and 27th January 201922nd January 2019 and 27th January 2019
```

[image]

My string only have one  but script seems replace whole texts, can any one know what's the reason for this error and a solution

or another way to do this.

Thanks a lot

Comment: HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression should be like

```
<?php


$string= '<p style="margin: 0 0 16px;">Your order is shipped and 
    it’s on the way to your address, It will receive to you within 
   <tag>current_date format=”jS F Y” oddt=”” shipdays=”16″</tag></p>';

    $search = "/<tag>(.*)<\/tag>/";

    $replace = "22nd January 2019 and 27th January";


    echo $sv= preg_replace($search,$replace,$string);
?>
```

The expression `/<tag>(.*)<\/tag>/` means any text between `<tag>` and  `</tag>`..

[image]